# mount.ntfs slowing computer without taking up CPU , showing "disk sleep"

Tags: ntfs

I have two NTFS partitions mounted in my filesystem. One of them hosts my projects, so it is very important.

Every so often, my computer gets sluggish, sometimes to the point of almost freezing up. I noticed that whenever that happens, the process `mount.ntfs` shows *`disk sleep`* in the CPU column of the System Monitor ksysguard (see screenshot below).

Notably, in those situations, the memory is *not* running out, and the CPUs are *not* running at full capacity.

What are possible explanations for this and how can I fix it?

I run Kubuntu 19.04, 64-bit.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Really, nobody has a clue?

Comment: [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1229643) may help.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It is a completely different scenario. Thanks anyway.

Comment: did you ever get an answer for this, i got the same problem and am researching if there is a solution? if i find any i'll post it as an awnser, but so far no luck...

Comment: Yes, let me write an answer below!

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that my disk was corrupted. Copying the data and replacing the disk fixed the issue.