# Connecting Ethernet Cable to Ubuntu Server Makes Terminal Response Very Slow

Tags: command-line, server, headless

I'm setting up an ubuntu server for the first time, and ran into an odd problem.

Basically, when I have my ethernet cable plugged in, the response to terminal commands gets very slow.

For example: the "sudo nano /etc/ufw/before.rules" command takes several seconds to open when the cable is plugged in, but opens instantly when I unplug the cable.

This kind of delay occurs with pretty much any command, but is fixed when I disconnect my ethernet cable.

I have ufw enabled, and configured to deny connections from all incoming connections except my SSH port, while allowing all outgoing connections.

The machine itself used to be a windows machine, but I have only the fresh install of ubuntu server on a new drive connected. I'm using a keyboard plugged directly into the tower.

Does anyone have any ideas of how I can fix this? I've attempted to google, but I haven't found anything related to this delay, since the lag isn't with individual characters as I type them.

Thanks  for any and all help!

EDIT 1: The problem persists even if I disable ufw.

EDIT 2:

```
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82579V Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 04
       serial: 50:46:5d:a1:ba:31
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.13-6 ip=192.168.0.104 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:37 memory:f7f00000-f7f1ffff memory:f7f39000-f7f39fff ioport:f040(size=32)
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: wlp7s0
       version: 01
       serial: dc:85:de:14:6f:33
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=5.4.0-65-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:18 memory:f7c00000-f7c7ffff memory:f7c80000-f7c8ffff
```

EDIT 3: I haven't installed any drivers yet, so I suppose that is the big issue. Does anyone know of a guide I could follow for learning to install drivers?
my hardware is as returned by lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579V Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev c4)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 7 (rev c4)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 8 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Z77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Pitcairn XT [Radeon HD 7870 GHz Edition]
02:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Oland/Hainan/Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7000 Series]
04:00.0 SATA controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller (rev 01)
05:00.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge (rev 03)
07:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
08:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042 SuperSpeed USB Host Controller
```

EDIT 4: I'm working on getting the ethernet drivers from the intel website (https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/13663), but I'm having difficulty with the command `apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`  from this page ( https://www.intel.ca/content/www/ca/en/support/articles/000005480/network-and-i-o/ethernet-products.html) Any tips, or documents I should look at for understanding this better?

EDIT 5: I've downloaded the driver, but am now trying to untar it, with little success

EDIT 6: turns I was downloading the html to a page that redirected to the download link.. in case someone in the future needs to know, the command "file" will tell you the file type the specified file `$ file filename.tar`
I'm following the instructions here: https://www.intel.ca/content/www/ca/en/support/articles/000005480/network-and-i-o/ethernet-products.html

EDIT 7: well, I think I installed the intel ethernet driver according to the instructions, but there is no difference in the behavior of the system. There i still 5-10 seconds delay after launching a terminal command

EDIT 8: I've given up for now, and just switched to Ubuntu desktop. I'll disable the gui drivers once I get everything set up and go from there

Comment: If you disable ufw do you get the same result with the cable plugged in? Please [edit] your question rather than just add a comment.

Comment: This sounds like a bad/missing driver for the ethernet adapter. Can you update your question to include the output of `sudo lshw -C network`? This will list specific information about your network devices and might lead to a solution.

Comment: @Matigo I think you're on the money. I haven't installed any drivers yet. I've been kind of muddling my way through it, do you know of any resources  I could look at?

Comment: Worth checking, maybe related: ------> [Bash tab completion appears to read uneeded file system info?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229643/bash-tab-completion-appears-to-read-uneeded-file-system-info/1229648#1229648)