# How to reset NFS client after interrupted connection?

Tags: mount, suspend, nfs

I have two devices: a laptop with Ubuntu 20.04, and a Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspberry Pi OS.

Both of these have an identical version of `nfs-kernel-server` and setup on them.

Both of of these share some of their directories with the other machine, sometimes simultaneously, via the NFS4 protocol.

Due to clumsiness, I quite often manage to interrupt these connections:

- I often shut the Raspberry down, while forgetting to unmount its share on the laptop
- my laptop either goes to sleep, or I log out / reboot, while the Raspberry is accessing its shares

In any case, neither machine in the role of client take these disruptions too well; attempts to unmount after-the-fact do not go well (endless waiting without any results), and other things can get impacted too: my Ubuntu sometimes starts to complain that no application is associated with opening `.txt` files (!)

**Question:**

How can I somehow reset these interrupted NFS connections on the clients (without rebooting)? 1.) To ease the unmounting 2.) To allow for a clean slate start for re-mounting.

**Details:**

`nfs-common` version on both machines: `1.3.4-2.5`

All these mounts are initiated manually (by running a script, on demand); none of them are in `/etc/fstab`. I have not supplied any options with the mount command whatsoever; it's as plain as:

```
sudo mount IP:/share /mountpoint
```

Comment: I have found this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/177039/448600 and this: https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000019722 Pretty much looks like I need to get more disciplined around my NFS connections :( At the same time it's extremely interesting that there's no feature in NFS to deal with this.

Comment: You need to specify the two options [soft,bg](https://askubuntu.com/a/1229648) and probably the third option `timeo`

Comment: @Raffa It's not in fstab, rather I use the mount command on demand; and I don't see these options in `man mount`: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/mount.8.html

Comment: It is in `man mount`... look for `-t` or `fstype`. The options themselves are in [man nfs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/nfs.5.html)... so basically you would use something like `sudo mount -t nfs -o soft,bg,timeo=30 IP:/share /mountpoint`

Comment: @Raffa I used your command with the modification of `-t nfs4` and `-v`. I made the client the Raspberry. Mounted my laptop's share. Set up a slideshow of images from the laptop's share. Then I sent the laptop to sleep. Slideshow app on Raspberry froze. `umount -v` says:"nfs4 mount point detected", and then: "umounted". Subsequent `umount -v` says "not mounted". But in the graphical file manager, the mount point keeps showing as "**inode/x-corrupted type**". Subsequent `mount -v` attempts return just one line about "trying", then exit. The mount point remains as corrupted inode.

Comment: Rebooting the Raspberry restores the mount point as healthy directory and mounting the laptop's share works again.

Comment: That is expected as nfs shares are complicated. Many factors are involved even DNS sometimes... There is nothing wrong withe using the frowned upon `umount -f` in this case as it might be the only way to refresh the state of the nfs share. It is helpful in case of an unreachable NFS system.

Comment: Does `umount -f` do something extra, even after a regular `umount` aready reports "not mounted"?

Comment: Yes, "It is helpful in case of an unreachable NFS system" this is also stated in `man umount` specifically under the option `-f`... [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/umount.8.html)... It refreshes the nfs mount state

Comment: @Raffa I did it with `umount -f -v`, and it worked! It said again, "nfs4 mount point detected", and then: "umounted". The graphical file manager kept showing the mount point as corrupted inode, so I closed the window, then reopened a new one, in which the mount point appears again as a healthy directory. Subsequently I could mount the share on it again. Do you want to add an answer? It could offer a solution that is ahead of several other resources.

Comment: With pleasure... answer on the way... one moment please. The most important thing is your nfs share is tamed now :) and as you mentioned, the solution for this issue is not easily available. So indeed it is worth an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You need to use the options `soft`, `bg`, and probably `timeo` like so:

  ```
  sudo mount -t nfs -o soft,bg,timeo=30 IP:/share /mountpoint
  ```

  Please see [man nfs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/nfs.5.html) for information and usage.
- When the connection to the NFS share is interrupted, refresh the mount-point with `umount -f` like so:

  ```
  sudo umount -f /mountpoint
  ```

  Then mount the NFS share again with the same options above.

  Please see [man umount](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/umount.8.html) for information and usage.

Comment: This worked; using the suggested mount options, after `umount -f` I could re-mount the share. Thank you!