# How to stop a service when a CIFS share becomes unavailable?

Tags: mount, systemd, services, cifs, init.d

I have a service that is started by a script `/etc/init.d/foo`. When a certain CIFS share (`//fileserver/multimedia on /home/username/multimedia type cifs`) becomes unavailable for any reason (unmounted, network down, cosmic rays,...), then I want the service `foo` to be stopped automatically. When the share is available again, then I want the service `foo` to (re)start automatically.
My criterium for "available" is: being able to access the files on the share.

How do I do that?

Comment: Cosmic rays will most likely take down your computer as well :) … to check for the availability of the mount anyway `showmount -e hostname`

Comment: Cosmic rays are pretty specific. A single high-energy proton will hit one server (or disk) but not touch the next one up in the rack. More worrisome might be coronal mass ejections that could take out entire data centers or power grids. Paranoia is very hard on my sleep schedule. :(

Comment: @doneal24 :) Nice one, but I would consider a scenario where a server is hit with **a single** proton pure bad luck or even personal :) .... [Cosmic rays are atom fragments that rain down on the Earth from outside of the solar system](https://www.space.com/32644-cosmic-rays.html) ... probably have backups elsewhere and sleep tight :)

Comment: @Raffa When you have 24PB of data on various storage platforms, sleeping tight is more difficult. And I do consider cosmic rays and other unpredictable events as being aimed at me personally. The universe has it in for me.

Comment: `showmount` is for NFS shares only, this is about a CIFS (Samba) share.

Comment: You people are such jokers! I love this community! <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My criterium for "available" is: being able to access the files on the
> share.

You can create a test file on the mount like so:

```
touch /home/username/multimedia/testfile
```

Then run a bash script to check for the accessibility of that test file every 60 seconds like so:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# Set the full path to the test file between " " in the next line
file="/home/username/multimedia/testfile"
while true; do
    if [ -f "$file" ]; then
        echo "File is available"
        # Your command/s here when the files on the mount are accessible.
    elif [ ! -f "$file" ]; then
        echo "File is NOT available"
        # Your command/s here when the files on the mount are NOT accessible.
    fi
    sleep 60
done
```

Comment: Would [inotifywait](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/inotifywait.1.html) be a more lightweight solution than a sleep/stat?

Comment: @doneal24 inotifywait is good for monitoring and reporting file events i.e. (read, write, modify, create, delete ... etc.) and although it has a `unmount` event but that is not how the OP defines availability ... so in this case, IMO, the bash script is a more proper solution ... and a `sleep 60` call in this context should be close if not equal to inotifywait regarding the system load.

Comment: @Raffa you are correct, when the network connection to the fileserver goes down (when the cleaning lady unplugs the server to plug in the vacuum cleaner) then that's not an unmount event if I'm not mistaken. The client still has a network connection, there just isn't a server alive at the other side.

Comment: Your solution is what I had also thought of myself before I asked my question. I'm going to leave the question open for a bit longer in case anyone else has another solution. If not, then I'll accept your answer in a few days.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse “if I'm not mistaken. The client still has a network connection, there just isn't a server alive at the other side.” … You are right, the mount will just become [stale](https://askubuntu.com/q/1328834/968501).

Comment: I tried with both sleep/stat and inotify, and I can confirm that there is no inotify event when I shut down my NAS or unplug the network cable. I'll update my question with my final script.

Answer (score 1):

Final solution based on @Raffa's accepted answer:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
file_list="/home/amedee/bin/file_list.txt"

all_files_exist () {
    while read -r line; do
        [ -f "$line" ]
        status=$?
        if ! (exit $status); then
            echo "$line not found!"
            return $status
        fi
    done < "$file_list"
}

start_crashplan () {
    echo "Starting CrashPlan"
    #/etc/init.d/code42 start
}

stop_crashplan () {
    echo "Stopping CrashPlan"
    #/etc/init.d/code42 stop
}

while true; do
    if all_files_exist; then
        echo "All files are available"
        start_crashplan
    else
        echo "Not all files are available"
        stop_crashplan
    fi
    sleep 60
done
```

- I want to test more than one share, so I moved the file test to a function `all_files_exist`.
- `file_list.txt` contains a list of `testfile`s on different shares that I want to check. They all have to be present, if even only one of them is missing or can't be reached, then the service must be stopped.

```
/home/amedee/Downloads/.testfile
/home/amedee/Multimedia/.testfile
/home/amedee/backup/.testfile
```

- I can add or remove shares without needing to modify the script, I only need to edit `file_list.txt` - even while the script is still running.
- Starting (or stopping) the service if it is already started (or stopped) is very much ok. The actual startup script itself takes care of checking if it has already started (or stopped).
- This is the version I used for debugging as an unprivileged user. In my live version I uncommented the `/etc/init.d/` lines and I removed all `echo` lines except `echo "$line not found!"`. The startup script already provides enough console output, and by using functions, I have made the script already very much human readable. You only need to read the `while true` loop at the bottom to understand what's going on.
- This script needs to be run at startup as root, so I call it from cron (`sudo crontab -u root -e`):

```
@reboot /home/amedee/bin/test_cifs_shares.sh
```