# Where is the tab completion "compspec" for commands like cat and ls defined?

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, ls, cat

Some pretext:

I'm installing Jenkins locally, and following the installation, I'm asked to produce a password from a text file in this folder: /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/

However, after entering
`cat /var/lib/jenkins-secrets/` and the first letter of the filename, lo-and-behold, tab and double tab do nothing - autocompletion is broken!

So after some reading, I've found out that autocompletion is defined via files called *compspecs*, and that the variables GLOBIGNORE and FIGNORE are used to define what is ignored in autocompletion. I'm curious now though, and I want to know exactly how ls and cat are made to ignore my /secrets/ folder's contents. After entering the following command to see the list of compspec files:

```
ls /etc/bash_completion.d
```

I only see the folders:

```
apt-linux-mint  git-prompt
```

Is there a general compspec for standard bash commands? What exactly stops me from double-tabbing in /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash tab completion appears to read uneeded file system info?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229643/bash-tab-completion-appears-to-read-uneeded-file-system-info)

Comment: I'd bet on permissions (or lack thereof), than any directories being ignored

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment from the user "muru" on my question, this was due to permissions, not compspecs.

Edit: Thanks to Raffa too for some useful info.